# Diagonalize and square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

> Diagonalize $\begin{bmatrix}
> 5 & 0 & 0\\
> 1 & 5 & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & 5\\
> \end{bmatrix}$ and find P and D such that $P^{-1}AP=D$

So I created the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda-5 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & \lambda-5 & 0\\
0 & -1 & \lambda-5\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Finding the determinant gives me $(\lambda-5)^3$ so $\lambda=5$

Subbing this in gives $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and I am unsure where to go from here?

Comment: this matrix cannot be diagonalised; is already in the canonical form.

Comment: This is because $(0/0/1)$ is (upto a factor) the only eigenvector of $A$, but we would need $3$ linear independent eigenvectors. The given form is called Jordan-normal-form.

Comment: In the case you need $A^2$, it is $$\pmatrix{25&0&0\\10&25&0\\1&10&25}$$